Detect when ScrollView has finished scrolling in iOS 17 SwiftUI
Using iOS 17 as minimum target and .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging) modifier.
I need a callback similar to scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation.
The goal is to get the callback only after the page changes and the animation finishes, not during the scrolling process or in a middle or so.
This is not a new question, but many other answer I've tried didn't worked well.
Is there maybe a new solution, specially if minimum iOS target for my project is iOS17?

@sweeper thats interesting, I think YES!

Are you using .scrollPosition modifier with a binding to observe the current "page" and need to take action or pass that binding further to other views?

@andrei-g I'd need event called when scrolling ended and page changed.

I understand, but that's not what I asked. I'll rephrase - if you use .scrollPosition to observe the current page, you can use an .onChange of that binding to run a debounced action, so that the action runs after a certain amount of time, usually based on the duration of any transition effects or animations applied to the scrollview. If you can update your question with a reproducible example, I can put up an answer showing this method. Or, you can use the method from Sweeper's answer, if you're comfortable with UIKit and Introspect.

Actually using of UIKit is not preferred, so I'd love to see how you could help!

As per my previous comment, please update your question with a minimum reproducible example so we have something to work with for the solution.

In iOS 18 there is onScrollPhaseChange, so you are not concerned with forward-compatibility. You can use SwiftUI-Introspect to intercept the scroll view delegate calls.
You write your own UIScrollViewDelegate that wraps the built-in delegate of ScrollView (after all, SwiftUI also needs to set its own delegate for its own purposes), and forwards every delegate method.
class ScrollViewObserver: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var wrapped: (any UIScrollViewDelegate)?
    var action: (() -> Void)?
    weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidScroll?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidZoom?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidScrollToTop?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewWillBeginDragging?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating?(scrollView)
        action?()
    }
    
    func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        wrapped?.scrollViewShouldScrollToTop?(scrollView) ?? true
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewWillBeginZooming?(scrollView, with: view)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset?(scrollView)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidEndDragging?(scrollView, willDecelerate: decelerate)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewDidEndZooming?(scrollView, with: view, atScale: scale)
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        wrapped?.scrollViewWillEndDragging?(scrollView, withVelocity: velocity, targetContentOffset: targetContentOffset)
    }
}

Then in introspect, you can replace the scroll view's delegate with an instance of ScrollViewObserver,
struct OnScrollEndModifier: ViewModifier {
    @StateObject var observer = ScrollViewObserver()
    let action: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 18, *) {
            content
                .onScrollPhaseChange { oldPhase, newPhase in
                    if newPhase == .idle && oldPhase != .idle {
                        action()
                    }
                }
        } else {
            content
                .introspect(.scrollView, on: .iOS(.v17)) { scrollView in
                    observer.action = action
                    // only replace the delegate when this is a new scroll view we haven't seen
                    if observer.scrollView != scrollView {
                        observer.wrapped = scrollView.delegate
                        scrollView.delegate = observer
                        observer.scrollView = scrollView
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onScrollEnd(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(OnScrollEndModifier(action: action))
    }
}

Usage:
ScrollView {
    // ...
}
.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
.onScrollEnd {
    print("Ended!")
}


thanks, I'll try this as like "backup" option, since I really don't want to use UIKit.
